# Multiple host names on vServer

Tags: server, nginx, hostname

I'm using two nginx files - one for the vue frontend and one for the nginx backend (proxy_pass).

The current spcecified host name in `/etc/hosts` which I'm using in the nginx vue config. Like:
`server_name inf-education-67.umwelt-campus.de;`

With using localhost in the nginx node config I keep getting errors when accessing it from out of the system. So I need a another host name on my vServer. Also for making the Axios calls to the backend. So for instance `server_name inf-education-backend.umwelt-campus.de`

How would I do that? (I'm really not familiar with that stuff)

Is this even the correct way?

Host file is:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 inf-education-67 #The current host name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You are talking about very different things. nginx uses **virtual** hosts, and that is what you need. Forget about your "real hostname".

Comment: And how would I solve my problem then? @pLumo
I need to be able to call my backend..